# How to tile or make bigger

Tags: visual-c++, opengl

How do I tile this? Or make it larger, to make the grass texture appear on the whole screen, like cover the whole floor panel?

Here the code and the result:

(Picture) http://tinypic.com/r/dyvc7t/6

```
glBegin(GL_QUADS);

glNormal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0);
glVertex3f(-140.0, 0.0,100.0);

glTexCoord3f(1.0,0.0,0.0);
glVertex3f(140.0, 0.0,100.0);

glTexCoord2f(1.0,1.0);
glVertex3f(140.0, 140.0,100.0);

glTexCoord2f(0.0,1.0);
glVertex3f(-140.0, 140.0,100.0);



glEnd();
glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the opengl code for a square:

```
glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // The bottom left corner
glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // The top left corner
glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // The top right corner
glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f); // The bottom right corner
```

Here is the same code, for a bigger square:

```
glVertex3f(-2.0f, -2.0f, 0.0f); // The bottom left corner
glVertex3f(-2.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f); // The top left corner
glVertex3f(2.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f); // The top right corner
glVertex3f(2.0f, -2.0f, 0.0f); // The bottom right corner
```

So if you want to make your polygon bigger, just change the numbers that define it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tile it, just use a 'for (int x = 0; x < so on...)' and a 'translate' method. Be sure to pop the matrix every time you translate a tile though, or it won't work.